# PHP Inventory Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that pulls data from a mysql database. I select the month and year and it should display the data I need, but when the year changed to 2015 I found that it will only show me data from 2014.  Here is the code and the URL string

```
$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month'])) {    
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Month'];

}


mysql_select_db($database_hk, $hk);<br>
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE `Month` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "text"));<br>
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $hk) or die(mysql_error());
<br>$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
```

---

The only way I was able to manually do it is to change the code to this

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE `Month` = %s AND year = '2015'", GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "text"));
```

I would like both the values of month and year to be set by 2 select drop down menus

```
<form method="get" name="form">
<table width="70%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <caption>
  <br>
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" align="center" scope="col"><h3>Inventory 
      <label for="month">Month:</label>
      <select name="Month" id="Month">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
        <option value="February">February</option>
        <option value="March">March</option>
        <option value="April">April</option>
        <option value="May">May</option>
        <option value="June">June</option>
        <option value="July">July</option>
        <option value="August">August</option>
        <option value="September">September</option>
        <option value="October">October</option>
        <option value="November">November</option>
        <option value="December">December</option>
    </select>
      <label for="year">Select:</label>
      <select name="year" id="year">
        <option>Year</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="View">
</table>
```

The URL after you press the view button is 
example.com/inventory_view.php?Month=January&year=2015&submit=View

I hope you can help
Thanks

Comment: It is implemented for the month already – so all you have to do is _understand_ that code, and then do it the same way for the year.

Answer (score 0):

You gave the answer yourself. If you don't pass the year you get all data in the specifiec month regardless of year. So also grab the year of your `$_GET` variable and expand your query like you did but only variable like the month.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still green around the ears when it comes to php. I tried <     $colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['Month, year'])) {    
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['Month, year'];>